# Insert JSON Array into mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a string that represents a JSON array into a mongodb collection with this,

```
String str = "[{\"id\":1,\"data\":\"data1\"},{\"id\":2,\"data\":\"data2\"},{\"id\":3,\"data\":\"data3\"}]";
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(str);
collection.insert(dbObject);
```

But I get the exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]
```

Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: is it normal that you've the same id everywhere ? i don't think it's the real reason but it's weird

Comment: @vincent I edited the code. Even though the ids are different, the same error is there..

Comment: do you need to save a single document with an array, or several documents?

Comment: adding your String from the MongoDB console is working. So this might be a bug in the MongoDB-Java-Driver.

Comment: @injecteer I want to save multiple documents.

Answer (score 3):

```
String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"data\":\"data1\"},{\"id\":2,\"data\":\"data2\"},{\"id\":3,\"data\":\"data3\"}]";
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("root", "sample", "root".toCharArray());
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost"), Arrays.asList(credential));
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("sample");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("loginTracking");
    List<Document> jsonList = new ArrayList<Document>();
    net.sf.json.JSONArray array = net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(json);
    for (Object object : array) {
        net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonStr = (net.sf.json.JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(object);
        Document jsnObject = Document.parse(jsonStr.toString());
        jsonList.add(jsnObject);

    }
    collection.insertMany(jsonList);
    mongoClient.close();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

as per [java doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) the `insert()` can accept either single `DBObject` or an array or `List` of them.

So, in order to save, you need to convert your JSON array into an array/List of DBObjects, or save each array's item

Answer (score 0):

**I found a good way for achieve that:**

```
(ArrayList<Document>) JSON.parse("[String json array]");
```

I had a problem with this, because i need append to this document a property that is a Json Array:

```
Document objAddendumVersion = new Document();
objAddendumVersion.append("_id", new ObjectId());
objAddendumVersion.append("Array", My Array here!);
```

But the problem is that Document.parse() doesn't work with Arrays, so i could solve it using the above line. So the final code is:

```
Document objAddendumVersion = new Document();
objAddendumVersion.append("_id", new ObjectId());
objAddendumVersion.append("Array", (ArrayList<Document>) JSON.parse("[String json array]"));
```

And it works perfect. Yes i know that exist more better ways for do that, but for the moment i'm using this.

I wait that be useful for someone with the same trouble.